# Relationship between an existing Household and a new Individual not added using civicrm webform

Tags: webforms, civicrm

When trying to add a new **CiviCRM Contact** of type **Individual** through a **webform** to a **existing Household**, the required **Relationship is not created**, although it is set up on the CiviCRM setting of the webform.
[image]

The **existing Household** is selected using the "**Existing Contact**" field of the civicrm webform.

When trying for the second time, the relationship between the Household and the Individual is correctly added.

Any idea what might be happening? I'm working with **Drupal 7.80** and **CiviCRM 5.36.1**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Cristina. there is a dedicated civicrm channel you might want to try http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: ps the answer may be to do with how many contacts you are creating via the form. the first relationship is for contacts 1 and 2, the second for 2 and 3 (guessing based on your screenshot)